# ADO app. under Windows 7 generates "error creating object. please verify that the microsoft data access components 2.1..."

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

Using Windows-7 sp1, ADO Applications that were built with Delphi-6/7 are generating:

"error creating object. please verify that the microsoft data access components 2.1 (or later) have been properly installed."

The error occurs only on my computer. All *.exe run error free on other computers.
This problem has appeared very recently, never had this error in the past.
It seems like it is a  Windows MDAC/WDAC problem.

How to verify microsoft data access components proper installation (MDAC/WDAC) on Windows-7 sp1 where those components are part of the operating system.

Please advise.

Best regards,
I. Nemlich

Comment: Are you tried re-installing MDAC(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793)?

Comment: this is really a problem, at length discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3a4ce946-effa-4f77-98a6-34f11c6b5a13/breaking-change-in-mdac-adodb-com-components-in-windows-7-service-pack-1-repost-with-msdn-liveid?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

Comment: Problem should be solved by installing latest patches. KB is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640696)

Comment: Please notice that with Windows-7 MDAC is WDAC and it is part of the operating system and not just a set of components.

Comment: You may look Into SysIntetnals Process Monitor to see how your program tries to find MDAC and where it fails I think some OLE servers' GUIDs were de - registered during some update

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded Process monitor and have to learn how to use. Do I need some other tools. I am not too familier with these tools.

Comment: This is my first time using ProcMon, it will take me some time to perform. Unless you can guide me how.

Comment: @user3166553, did you read the links I gave you?

Comment: Sure, I read and even inststalled kb264696. It seems like some files were unregistered during update operation. I hope that Sysinternals Process Monitor will help me to solve this case. If you have a good advice, please go on and let us know about. Many thanks. Nemlich

Answer (score 0):

This case has been solved with the help of "Process Monitor".
Some entries vanished from the Registry.

Many thanks to those how tried to help.
I. Nemlich